# How to reference a variable inside a module.exports in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a module written like below:

```
module.exports = {
    port: '1337',
    facebook: {
        clientID: '123456789',
        clientSecret: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k',
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:1337/oauth/facebook/callback'
    }
};
```

What I would like to do is use the port variable in the callbackURL:

```
callbackURL: 'http://localhost:1337/oauth/facebook/callback'
```

I tried:

```
callbackURL: 'http://localhost:'+ this.port +'/oauth/facebook/callback'
```

but obviously that's not correct since the facebook is another object. So, can someone solve this one, and please any additional reading that you have (in terms of deeper understanding) is welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just declare it above the `module.exports` as an ordinary variable:

```
var port = '1337';
module.exports = {
    port,
    facebook: {
        clientID: '123456789',
        clientSecret: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k',
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:'+ port + '/oauth/facebook/callback'
    }
};
```

You can put `module.exports` wherever you want in your file, you can even perform some logic (like retrieving settings from a file or another resource).

Comment: Great, thanks - will accept the answer asap the grace period for acceptance is over.

Answer (score 2):

I use the below construct all the time,

```
const that = module.exports = {
    port: '1337',
    facebook: {
        clientID: '123456789',
        clientSecret: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k',
        callbackURL: `http://localhost:${that.port}/oauth/facebook/callback`
    }
};
```

Even if you were trying to use `this.port` in the outermost object, it still will not give the desired results, because the `this` will not point to the object you're exporting in the `module.exports`. I'm not sure of the answer to this - no pun intended. I'm still researching and experimenting to find out more, can report back once I know more.

Comment: Upon second look, nothing stops you from referencing `module.exports` inside the `module.exports` object itself either. But using a shorter reference name, `that` in this case, is shorter which can make for less clutter and thus neater looking code.